# Python - Iterating over all text files recursively

Tags: python, list, directory

I am creating a text parser with python 3.6.  I have a file layout like below:

(The real file structure I will be using is much more extensive than this.)

```
-Directory(main folder)
    -amerigroup.txt
    -bcbs.txt
    childfolder
         -medicare.txt
```

I need to extract text into 2 different lists (going through and appending to my ever-growing lists).  Whenever I run my current code, I can't seem to get my program to open up my medicare.txt file to read and extract the information.  I get an error stating that there is no such file or directory: 'medicare.txt'.

My goal is to get the data from the 3 files and extract it in one go.  How do I get the amerigroup and bcbs data then go into the childfolder and get medicare.txt, then repeat that for all branches of my file path?

I am simply trying to open and close my text files in this code snippet.  Here's what I have so far:

```
import re
import os
import pandas as pd

#change active directory
os.chdir(r'\\company\Files\HomeDrive\user\My Documents\claimstest')
#rootdir = r'\\company\Files\HomeDrive\user\My Documents\claimstest'

#set up Regular Expression objects to parse X12
claimidRegex = re.compile(r'(CLM\*)(\d+)')
dxRegex = re.compile(r'(ABK:)(\w\d+)(\*|~)(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?')

claimids = []
dxinfo = []

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(topdir):
    for name in files:
        cid = []
        dx = []
        if name.lower().endswith(exten):
            data = open(name, 'r')
            data.close()
```

Thank you so much for taking your time to assist me on this!

edit:  I have tried using walk to no avail so far.  My most recent attempt (I tried using txtfile_full_path as well--did not work):

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filename in os.walk(base_dir):
    for filename in filename:
        #defining file type
        txtfile=open(filename,"r")
        txtfile_full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        print(filename)
```

edit2 for anyone interested.  This was my final solution to the problem:

```
import re
import os
import pandas as pd


#change active directory
os.chdir(r'\\company\Files\HomeDrive\user\My Documents\claimstest')
base_dir = (r'\\company\Files\HomeDrive\user\My Documents\claimstest')

#set up Regular Expression objects to parse X12
claimidRegex = re.compile(r'(CLM\*)(\d+)')
dxRegex = re.compile(r'(ABK:)(\w\d+)(\*|~)(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?(ABF:)?(\w\d+)?(\*|~)?')

claimids = []
dxinfo = []

for dirpath, dirnames, filename in os.walk(base_dir):
    for filename in filename:
        txtfile_full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        x12 = open(txtfile_full_path, 'r')
        for i in x12:
            match = claimidRegex.findall(i)
            for word in match:
                claimids.append(word[1])
        x12.seek(0)
        for i in x12:
            match = dxRegex.findall(i)
            for word in match:
                dxinfo.append(word)
        x12.close()

datadic = dict(zip(claimids, dxinfo))
```

Comment: You should use something like `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`

Comment: So, think about it, your working directory doesn't see any `medicare.txt`, you have to give it either a full path or a relative path it can recognize.

Comment: juan, I gave this a shot, but I just keep getting the same error.  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'medicare.txt'



`for dirpath, dirnames, filename in os.walk(base_dir):
    for filename in filename:
        #defining file type
        txtfile=open(filename,"r")
        txtfile_full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        print(filename)`

Comment: I have *no idea* what you are doing there. It *looks* like you are **not** using `txtfile_full_path` as an argument to `open`, and rather, continued to use `filename`, but who knows, since I have no idea where your comment begins or ends. Please edit your original question and add the code there, were it would be readable.

Comment: my mistake.  i edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *pass the full path* to `open`. Just creating a string variable somewhere won't do anything for you! So the following should avoid your error:

```
txt_list = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filename in os.walk(base_dir):
    for filename in filename:
        # create full path
        txtfile_full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        with open(txtfile_full_path) as f:
            txt_list.append(f.read())
```

It should be easy enough to integrate the segregation based on your regexes now...

Comment: This is great, thank you!

This will work no matter how deep my file path is, right?

Comment: @AngusGray it should.